# Как передавать данные между Activity?

Tags: java, android

Есть `long timefinal` - время, которое нужно передать следующей `Activity` в `TextView`.

Как правильно это сделать?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Через интент:

**FirstActivity.java**

```
...

Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putString("tag", timefinal);
startActivity(intent);

...
```

**SecondActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String timefinal = getIntent().getString("tag");
    textView.setText(timefinal);
}
```