# Передача заполненого поля EditText в другие Activity

Tags: android

Всем привет!
Есть приложение которое конектится с Web-Service, в Activity "Настройки" я заполняю два поля (EditText) Адрес сервиса и его Порт, как мне передавать Адрес и Порт в другие Activity

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как передавать данные между Activity?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/559123/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-activity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю вам в любом случае нужно сохранять эти данные, они же будут и при следующем запуске использоваться?!

Вводите данные в EditText, сохраняете их где угодно, пусть будет `SharedPreference`

И в других активити считываете данные из того места где сохранили.

А если просто нужно передать в другое активити, то почитайте про передачу данных через `Intent`

Answer (score 2):

Вы при открытии новой `Activity` вы создаете `Intent`. ВЫ можете положить туда какие-то данные в `Bundle`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key", editText.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent)
```

А во второй `Activity`:

```
String enteredText = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
```

В `Bundle` можно класть столько полей сколько вам необходимо. Единственное, что нужно помнить, что его размер ограничен 1MB, а это значит, что он не предназначен для передачи больших объемов данных.